# trace of 2-tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have no idea about how to compute trace of a tensor.In particular I want to calculate trace of some power of shape operator over some domain.The notation may help.
$$Tr^{T_tM}(\mathcal{S}_{\eta}^{i})$$.

You can assume $\mathcal{S}_\eta$ as a 2-tensor $T$. and $i$ is the power of that operater.So it will suffice if you tell me $$Tr(T^i)=?$$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your notation correctly you have a two-tensor defined at every point on your manifold and want to take the trace of some power of this tensor at some point, $t$?

If this is so then you should choose some basis in the tangent space at $t$, with respect to which the tensor $T$ has components $T^{a b}$. Taking the $i$th power can be expressed as (matrix) multiplication of the components $(T^{i})^{ab} = T^{a}{}_{p}T^{p}{}_{q}\ldots T^{s}{}_{t}T^{tb}$ where I'm assuming you have a metric to lower indices.

The trace is taking by contracting $a$ and $b$: $tr_{t}(T^{i}) = (T^{i})^{a}{}_{a}$. If you also want the functional trace over the manifold then the above answer gives you the trace at t, so you would integrate $Tr(T^{i}) = \int_{M} d \textrm{vol}(t)\,tr_{t}(T^{i})$.

If this is not what you're looking for the please clarify the question.